# query couchbase spacial view with nodejs

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I was unable to find examples or any directions on how to query spacial view with node.js.

I have a view that should receive bounding box for north east and south west coordinates and return every document that is inside the bbox.

can anyone provide me with example/link on how to do it?

spacial view code:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.geometry && doc.properties.type == "poi" ) {
    emit({ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [doc.geometry.coordinates[0].lon, doc.geometry.coordinates[0].lat]}, null);
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this might help https://github.com/PatrickHeneise/geolocation-demo

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering the same thing tonight and in the meantime I have just used the REST port.  You can get the exact URL by clicking on the URL form the results window on the console for your spatial view.

Comment: Yes, eventually this is exactly what I did. Anyway, no solution yet.